# the data sent to users from servers,is it data out form s3 or data out from ec2 ?refering to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I was using the aws monthly calculator and hence got this question.
The data is sent from the servers to the users of the app.Now the data is data out for sure.
But from where??..Out from s3 or form ec2 and if one then why not the other.

Comment: its better you provide the link as well and is your app using both S3 and ec2 ?

Answer (score 0):

This depends *entirely* on how **you** design your application.  Most applications would have some data out from EC2 and some data out from S3.  It depends on which system the browser is actually connected to when the data is sent, which is determined by your code.

Fundamentally, though, the difference shouldn't matter, because data out from S3 to the Internet and data out from EC2 to the Internet are billed at the same price.